# Optimize SQL query multiple joins with count tables

Tags: mysql, sql

By any chance you would be able to help optimize this query without me showing you the tables?

My original table that all of these queries are derived from has the following columns and the table is named laterec-students

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| studentid | name  | class | latetime             | waived |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID1111STU  | Stu 1 | 1A   |2012-01-09 08:09:00   |Waived  |



SELECT A.class, NoStudentsLate, 1xLATE, 2xLATE FROM (

  SELECT 
         class, 
         count(DISTINCT studentid) AS NoStudentsLate
    FROM `laterec-students` 
   WHERE waived!="Waived" 
   GROUP BY class

) AS A 
LEFT JOIN (

  SELECT class, count(distinct studentid) AS 1xLATE from (
       SELECT `laterec-students`.class, `laterec-students`.studentid
         FROM `laterec-students` 
        WHERE waived!="Waived"
        GROUP BY studentid
       HAVING count(studentid)=1) as temp 
  GROUP BY class
) AS B ON A.class=B.class

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT class, count(distinct studentid) AS 2xLATE from (
    SELECT `laterec-students`.class, `laterec-students`.studentid
      FROM `laterec-students` 
     WHERE waived!="Waived"
     GROUP BY studentid
    HAVING count(studentid)=2) as temp 
  GROUP BY class
) AS C ON A.class=C.class
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class | Total # of students late | # late 1 times | # late 2 times |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1A    |    5                     |     3          |     2          |
| 1B    |    3                     |     3          |     0          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So what this means, in class 1A, there are a total of 5 student late as counted using the student id. Out  of this 5, 3 students are late once, and 2 students are late twice.

Again in class 1B, total 3 students are late, and all of them are only late once.

Comment: It would help if you explain your business logic. What are 1xlate and 2xlate supposed to mean? As it is you're expecting us to figure out what you want to do by reading your code. This is hard. Thanks.

Comment: ok, basically the table contains data of number of students that are late. I have edited the above

Comment: what does it mean to be "late?" I still can't tell what you're trying to do here. (Please excuse me for being picky, but I have found that when I really understand what my query is supposed to produced, that it is easier to optimize it.)

Comment: I have added a sample data to the table above. basically, this system is for a school to record student who attends school late, any one who come in late will have their data recorded in the table above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I understood your query, but the following works with my [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4113c/1).

```
SELECT
  class,
  SUM(cnt > 0) AS NoStudentsLate,
  SUM(cnt = 1) AS 1xLate,
  SUM(cnt = 2) AS 2xLate
FROM
(
  SELECT class, studentid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM `laterec-students`
  WHERE waived!='Waived'
  GROUP BY class, studentid
) t
GROUP BY class;
```

Comment: Hi Peter,Thank for your answer, however my 1xLate and 2xLate are not table of its own, there are generated by the sub queries

Comment: Have you tried the query? I am also generating those columns.